# Removing Duplicate from 2 datatables

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 Datatables with column X. I want to delete the entire row if column x value is in both datatables. What is the best way to do this? This is what I tried but it doesn't work not sure if this is the best way anyway.

```
Private Function SplitData(ByVal dtSome As DataTable, ByVal dtAll As DataTable) As DataTable
    ' This Routine Creates the Plant DataDictionary

    Dim SomelIndex As Integer = 0
    Do While SomelIndex < dtSome.Rows.Count
        Dim AlllIndex As Integer = 0
        Do While AlllIndex < dtAll.Rows.Count
            If dtAll.Rows(AlllIndex).Item("x").ToString = dtSome.Rows(SomelIndex).Item("x").ToString Then
                'I have the below to removes because it doesn't appear to actually remove the rows even if it gets here  
                '  dtAll.Rows.RemoveAt(AlllIndex)

                dtAll.Rows.Remove(dtAll.Rows(AlllIndex))
                Exit Do
            Else
                AlllIndex += 1
            End If
        Loop
        SomelIndex += 1
    Loop

    Return dtAll


End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what my problem was but this is a bit neater of a solution. Instead of using 2 do while loop I am using a for each and a Do While Loop. Prob not the most efficient way but the below definitely works and deletes the data

```
Public Shared Function SplitDataTables(ByVal dtSome As DataTable, ByVal dtAll As DataTable) As DataTable

    For Each drSome As DataRow In dtSome.Rows
        Dim intIndex As Integer = 0
        Do While intIndex < dtAll.Rows.Count
            If drSome.Item("X").ToString = dtAll.Rows(intIndex).Item("X").ToString Then
                dtAll.Rows.Remove(dtAll.Rows(intIndex))
                Exit Do
            Else
                intIndex += 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next

    Return dtAll

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to find the common rows and then remove them.

```
Private Function SplitData(ByVal dtSome As DataTable, ByVal dtAll As DataTable) As DataTable
    ' This Routine Creates the Plant DataDictionary

    Dim common = (
        From r1 In dtAll.AsEnumerable()
        Join r2 In dtSome.AsEnumerable() On r1("x") Equals r2("x")
        Select r1
    ).ToList()

    For Each r In common
        dtAll.Rows.Remove(r)
    Next

    Return dtAll

End Function
```

I don't know if this is the "best" way, but to me it makes it easier to see what is going on than the nested loops.

Note that [`DataTable.AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Do you know what wrong with my nested loop by chance?

Comment: It gives me an sytax error stating asenumerable is not a member of system.data.datatable

Comment: @codeMonger123 You will need to add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll.

Comment: If there is possible a way to use something other than link that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Just before you return dtAll, add this line:

```
dtAll.AcceptChanges()
```

It will commit the changes you made since "the last time AcceptChanges was called"...or in your particular case, since you invoked the function.

Comment: Well when it gets to the remove line I noticed it does remove it in the next loop.

Comment: I can give that a try though because it looks like my code should work.

Comment: Right...but that's only inside of the function itself. When you try to use dtAll outside of your function, it probably goes back to the way it was when you first invoked the function, right?

Comment: One other thing: you could and would probably be better served to call this as a sub and set dtAll as a byRef parameter.  The difference is that changes made to a byRef parameter will be passed back to the argument itself.  

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx  <-- this will explain the differences.

Comment: Sorry typo it doesn't actually remove the line. I say that because when I remove it from dtall the count is always 150 inside the function as it is looping

Comment: No worries. We'll blame context for that one, not you. It's always context's fault. ;)

Comment: @SEFL   [Parameter Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229015.aspx) `DO NOT pass reference types by reference` A `DataTable` is a reference type.

Comment: @shadow: they also state that there are limited exceptions to the rule. A function that modifies the data within the datatable and returns the datatable would likely qualify as one of those exceptions, since the table itself is the output.